# Is it appropriate to use a colon in this situation?

Tags: commas, parentheses, colons

For example:

```
I did a quick search and found the following, but I am still confused: 
List item 1
List item 2
etc.
```

Is it appropriate to still use the colon after adding the statement `, but I am still confused`? The colon doesn't feel as if it fits so well after the statement is added.

Should `but I am still confused` be moved elsewhere (such as into parentheses)?

I feel as though this reads better:

```
I did a quick search and found the following (but I am still confused): 
List item 1
List item 2
etc.
```

Are they both correct? Is one preferable over the other? Or is there a better solution outside of these two options?

Comment: Either the first or the second with the colon *after* the parenthetical. The colon before the parenthetical makes no sense.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Alright, edited the position of the parenthetical. Go ahead an post this as an answer if you feel that it answers the question!

Comment: I am rep capped for today. Someone else can take it. They are probably already writing it up anyway.

Comment: I agree with Reg that the comma before the parenthetical is not acceptable, but this is another case where the parenthetical has a say in the form of the matrix sentence (albeit only its punctuation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to end the introductory sentence with a colon immediately after the word *following*, you can achieve it by phrasing the sentence along these lines:

> I did a quick search and—though I remain somewhat confused—found the following:
>
> List item 1
>
> List item 2
>
> etc.

Having said that, I don't think that anything is wrong with either of the two options that you offer in your original question. As both RegDwight and Edwin Ashworth noted in their comments, putting the colon before the parenthetical, as in

> I did a quick search and found the following: (but I am still confused)

is not a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered this version?

> I did a quick search and found the following, but I am still confused *with*:
>
> List item 1
>
> List item 2
>
> etc.

Comment: In this context, the list isn't what the person is confused with.

Comment: @Lemmings19 Oh, I misunderstood... Sorry about that!